# Is today's chess.com daily puzzle a draw (as hinted at in the puzzle title)?

Tags: analysis, draw, puzzles

Today's daily puzzle on chess.com is called [Desperation Draw](https://www.chess.com/forum/view/daily-puzzles/4-5-2017-desperation-draw):

**White to move**

```
[FEN "r5k1/P4ppp/8/8/p1p1P3/4KP2/2P3PP/5R2 w - - 0 1"]

1. Rb1 Rf8 2. Rb8  *
```

One of the commentators asked:

> What draw?

I agree with this. I think this is a simple win for white who threatens to promote soon when black has no counter play, e.g. 2...a3 3. Rxf8+ Kxf8 4. a8Q+ Ke7 5. Qxa3.

My question is, **am I missing the draw in the position above?**

Comment: Stockfish evaluates the final position as +67.5, after 2. ... a3 it is mate in 7.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you are not.

It's an easy win for white as far as I can see.

Comment: After solving the puzzle, I had the same thought: I didn't like the title (unless misdirection was part of the fun).  Then I wondered if it had to do with a different definition of draw than the chess definition - say, an American football play, or some such.  Then I decided I didn't care enough to do research.  :)